# Pass properties but make exceptions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spread

There is something common that sometimes we all do. Wrap dom elements in custom components

`<CustomComponet id="abc" title="abc" nonDomProp="abc" ...andsoforth />`

Custom component in this example wraps `button` which has the properties `id` and `title` but not `nonDomProp` so I get a warning which makes sense because nonDomProp doesn't exist in the wrapped `button` DOM element and I am just passing all props to the `button` DOM element with the spread operator `<button {...props} />`

One way to solve this is by manually passing only the props that `button` will use, but I was wondering if there is a way to tell the spread operator to use all the passed `...props` but to ignore `nonDomProp`.

I have tried to do a Google search and I have not been able to find what I am looking for so I thought maybe SO would point me in the right direction.

Comment: `{ nonDomProp, ...props }`? This isn't specific to React, just basic destructuring.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, is it just filtering the props out of the props object?

Comment: I found it on the link provided below: *Rest properties collect the remaining own enumerable property keys that are not already picked off by the destructuring pattern.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destructure the *props* object with this:

```
const { nonDomProp, ...propsButton } = props;
return(
 <button {...propsButton} />
)
```

Or directly from the argument of the *CustomComponent* function:

```
const CustomComponent = ({ nonDomProp, ...props }) => {
...
return(
 <button {...props} />
)
}
```

Docs: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread#rest-properties

Comment: I need to read on this but if I understand this correctly ```{ nonDomProp, ...props }``` is it just filtering out ```nonDomProp```? Either way, thanks so much for the quick response! I hope this helps others as well!

Comment: Found it in the link you provided *Rest properties collect the remaining own enumerable property keys that are not already picked off by the destructuring pattern.*